# QListWidget, получить индекс элемента по элементу

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Мне нужно получить индекс элемента из `QListWidgetItem` по самому элементу (`QListWidgetItem`).

Нашел метод, но не понял его: `indexFromItem(item)`

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QModelIndex QListWidget::indexFromItem(const QListWidgetItem *item) const
>
> Возвращает QModelIndex, связанный с данным элементом.

Т.к. вы не предоставили свой пример,
приведу свой пример, который демонстрирует работу `indexFromItem(item)`

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton,\
    QListWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QListWidget, QApplication


class ItemWidget(QWidget):
    itemDeleted = pyqtSignal(QListWidgetItem)

    def __init__(self, text, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self._item = item                       # Сохраните ссылку на объект элемента списка
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QLineEdit(text, self))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('x', self, clicked=self.doDeleteItem))

    def doDeleteItem(self):
        self.itemDeleted.emit(self._item)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(200, 40)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        # Кнопка очистки
        self.clearBtn = QPushButton('Очистить все элементы', self, clicked=self.doClearItem)
        layout.addWidget(self.clearBtn)

        # Добавить данные
        self.testData()

    def doDeleteItem(self, item):
        # Получить строку, соответствующую ему по элементу
        row = self.listWidget.indexFromItem(item).row()              #   !!!
        # Удалить item
        item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
        # Удалить виджет
        self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
        del item

    def doClearItem(self):
        # Очистить все элементы
        for _ in range(self.listWidget.count()):
            # Удалить item
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            # Удалить виджет
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            del item

    def testData(self):
        # Создать данные
        for i in range(20):
            item = QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            widget = ItemWidget('item: {}'.format(i), item, self.listWidget)
            # Сигнал удаления привязки
            widget.itemDeleted.connect(self.doDeleteItem)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста **ВСЕГДА** предоставляйте пример, который демонстрирует проблему !!!